# How can I index elements with SQL?

Tags: sql, counting

I have a data set with multiple units, each having multiple data points

```
unit  data_point
   1         0.6
   1         1.3
   2         0.5
   2         1.6
   2         2.8
```

How can I create a new variable `X` indicating the index of the data_point information (not the total `count()` for the units):

```
unit  data_point  X
   1         0.6  1
   1         1.3  2
   2         0.5  1
   2         1.6  2
   2         2.8  3
```

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function, as in:

```
select
  unit,
  data_point,
  row_number() over (partition by unit order by data_point) as x
from my_table
```